# win service app problem

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am writing a windows service app and I use the timer control. In OnStart() event of my windows service I start the timer and I want that StartTimer() is called every one minute, but nothing is happening.

What is wrong here?

thanks.

myWinService.cs:::

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Interval=60000;
            timer1.Start();


        }

   private void StartTimer()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\mcWindowsService.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            m_streamWriter.WriteLine(Environment.UserName.ToString()+tik.ToString());
            m_streamWriter.Flush();

        }

  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tik++;
            StartTimer();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code that registers the timer1_Tick to timer1?

Comment: @Gunner:what should i write??

Comment: How are you testing the service? Are you sure it is starting correctly or even installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @Gunner, you have not hooked up the `Timer.Tick` event.

In your`OnStart` method, you need to register the `timer1_Tick` method with the `Tick` event:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

Comment: I am guessing he might have used the Visual Studio designer to add the Timer to the service and hook up the handler to the event (hence the very Visual Studio-like name of the handler).

Comment: @Oded:when i test my code in win app works true without adding 
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;    but in my win service dosn't.

Comment: @na.fa - Chances are good that that line of code _does_ exist in the form, only generated by the designer.

Comment: @Oded:i edited my code:::"     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Interval = 60000;
            timer1.Start();
            

        }  but dosn't work.

Comment: @na.fa - sorry - I got the code slightly wrong, forgot to new up the EventHandler.

Comment: @Oded:hi.i try alot from yesterday,but my timer dosn't work.can you make a small win service with timer for me??or give to me a link of this kind program.thanks alot.

Comment: @na.fa - The MSDN page has an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx